# Isometry vs. measure preserving?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, differential-geometry

Consider functions between two measured metric spaces. What is the relation between an isometry and a function which preserves the measure of subsets?

This question arose in my head as I thought about the surjection of the Cantor set onto $[0,1]$.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242837/lebesgue-measure-is-invariant-under-isometry) question had something, but I don't think it completely settles it.

Comment: The way your question is phrased, there could be absolutely no relation between the metric and the measure. Say you had $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric and the counting measure.

Comment: Begin with linear maps on $\mathbb R^n.$ Distance (and orientation) preserving are matrices $SO_n,$ while measure preserving is the much larger $SL_n.$

Comment: If you restrict to Riemannian manifolds and the measure induced by the Riemannian metric, all local isometries are measure-preserving.

Answer (score 4):

Isometries preserve the *metric space* structure. *Measure space* structure is generally an  entirely different thing;  preserving one thing is unrelated to preserving the other. However, there is an exception: [Hausdorff measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure), which are defined *solely in terms of the metric* and therefore behave well under isometries. Precise statement: if $f:X\to Y$ is a bijection between metric spaces such that $d_Y(f(a),f(b))=d_X(a,b)$ for all $a,b\in X$, then the pushforward of Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^d$ on $X$ under $f$ is the Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^d$ on $Y$.

By the way, the counting measure can be understood as the $0$-dimensional Hausdorff measure, so it is included here.  Of course, the counting measure behaves   well under any bijection.

I could not come up with a natural situation  in which measure-preserving maps are automatically metric-preserving. The problem is that it's hard to construct a metric from a measure without involving additional structures, such as topology. E.g.,  one could try to construct a metric $d_\mu$ from measure $\mu$ by letting
$$d_\mu(a,b)=\inf\{\mu(E): a,b\in E,\ \text{ $E$ is connected}\}$$
but this involves the topological structure too. The above is a sensible construction on the real line; e.g., you   get the standard metric from the Lebesgue measure in this way.

Comment: What about the converse *for Hausdorff measures* specifically? i.e. if $f: X \to Y$ is a bijection between metric spaces, such that for all $A$ in the sgima algebra of $X$ we have $\cal H^d(A) = \cal H^d(f(A))$. Does that then also imply that $f$ is metric-preserving?