# Show that two Lebesgue measures are the same

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

I have the following sets:
$$
\begin{align}
    A = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|x\geq0, y\geq 0, |x|^{3}+|y|^{3} < 1 \}, \\
    B = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|x\leq0, y\geq 0, |x|^{3}+|y|^{3} < 1 \}
\end{align}
$$

and I have just shown that they are both Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and I would now like to answer the following question:

"Show that $\lambda^{2}(A)$ = $\lambda^{2}(B)$ where $\lambda^{2}$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R}^{2}),\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^{2}))$. (Hint: You do not need to calculate $\lambda^{2}(A)$ or $\lambda^{2}(B)$)."

So how can I show that these measures are in fact the same without calculating them? The only difference between these two sets are that A can be sketched in the 1.quadrant and B in the 2.quadrant so there is a symmetry. Can I use this somehow and the fact that the Lebesgue measure is invariant under translation?

Any input?

Comment: Apply change of variable formula to $(x,y) \to (-x,y)$.

Comment: Yes that is good advise but we haven't covered that yet in the course so I am not allowed to use that fact unfortunately. We have covered R. Schilling, chapter 1-9.

Answer (score 1):

The Lebesgue measure is not only invariant under translations, but also invariant under isometries,
see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242837/lebesgue-measure-is-invariant-under-isometry) for example.

Note that this is also true for reflections and rotations (in fact, reflections and rotations are isometries).

There is no translation between $A$ and $B$, but there is an isometry.
Can you find it?

Comment: Thanks. I don't think we have covered 'invariance under isometry' but in the textbook (R. Schilling) there is a Theoerm 4.7(ii) saying that: "$\lambda^{n}$ is invariant under motion: $\lambda^{n}(R^{-1}(B)) = \lambda^{n}(B)$, where R is a motion, i.e. a combination of translations, rotations and reflections."\\
Would that be applicable to the case here, that A is a reflection of B and vice verca and therefore the Lebesgue measure is the same?

Comment: @EodEnaj yes, this sounds like a good idea! And reflections are a type of isometry anyways. And (if I am not mistaken) all isometries can be constructed using a combination of reflections and rotations (you do not need this fact for your question, just FYI).